# 8086 Data Segment MASM

Tags: masm, x86-16

Given this data segment:

```
.data
vara dw 0AB0h
varb db 'C'
varc db 'DEF',0
vard db 65
vare db '90','$'
```

1. How do you find the offset into the Data Segment of the variable vard ?
2. How do you find how many bytes will have been written to the standard output device after all these instructions have been executed:

   mov dx, offset varc

   mov ah,9

Comment: For #2: Why not just run the program and count them? No need to ask us what the program does when you have a computer that will tell you.

Comment: I know the answer but I don't know how to get the answer

Comment: Read [the documentation for function 9](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-9.html).

Answer (score 0):

> How do you find the offset into the Data Segment of the variable vard ?

Just **count** all the data that preceeds the *vard* variable.

You have 1 word, 1 char, 3 chars and 1 byte.

**7**

---

> How do you find how many bytes will have been written to the standard output device after all these instructions have been executed:

Again count all the data up until but **not including** the next **$** sign.

You have 3 chars, 1 byte, 1 byte and 2 chars.

**7**

Comment: There may be other variables preceding the `vard` variable coming from other translation units. The answer is not known until link time.

Answer (score 0):

(1) The offset into the Data Segment of vard is:  **offset vard** .  Its value is resolved, and cannot be known until, link time.

(2) Assuming you are performing (though I see no int 21h in your question):

```
mov dx, offset varc
mov ah,9
int 21h
```

you will output seven bytes.  All fields involved are byte so there will be no alignment padding intermixed, and the assembler/linker will not reorder variables, even if they stand alone (ie. are not embedded in a structure).